# android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission in android

Tags: android

Is this permission will work below 19 api or not android and second thing if we grant this permission then should i take  permission to user or not, if yes  then on which sdk level need to ask? not getting proper documentation of that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this permission will work below 19 api or not

The permission itself [`PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) was only added in API 23 and the [`UsageStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) was only added in API 21. There is no way to use these APIs on earlier versions of Android because they simply do not exist.

> if we grant this permission then should i take permission to user or not, if yes then on which sdk level need to ask? not getting proper documentation of that.

The [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) documentation is what you are looking for. On any device running API 23+ your users will be able to revoke permissions at will, and in general you should be asking for permissions at run time.

However, you will want to pay attention to this note in the `UsageStatsManager` documentation:

> This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

Answer (score 1):

This permission is added in `API level 21` that is `LOLLYPOP`

And there is no need to grant this permission at run time.

Unfortunately you can't request the `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` at runtime like you do with a dangerous permission. The user need to manually grant the permission through the Settings application as explained in the `UsageStatsManager` documentation: [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html)

**FYI:**  Run time permission are granted for `API level 23` or above that is `MARSHMALLOW`